# TP link range extender connection keeps dropping despite strong router-wifi signal

Tags: wireless-extender

I have a xfinity xfi gateway with a 900mbps plan but my house being too big, I don't get a strong signal. With speedtest I get about 5-6mbps on my macbook.

So I bought a tp-link range extender (RE 505X), but I am facing the exact same issues with it that I faced with my previous tp-link range extender:

I set the extender network with a different SSID (with a " ext" suffix) and connected my macbook pro with it. It works fine for a few minutes giving me 200mpbs, but then after a few minutes nothing works. There is no internet traffic, but the signal is always there.

speedtest doesn't even start.

How do I troubleshoot this? I know the problem is not with the range extender since this is new, and the previous one also had the same problem.

Comment: Does the problem only happen when you're connected to the range extender network?

Comment: Yes, @music2myear that's correct.